# Using multiple HDRIs when moving between rooms

Tags: lighting, hdri, world

I want to "walk" a rendered object from one room to another.  I have filmed and tracked a background plate of the camera move and the room.

The object contains reflective sections, and the two rooms are lit quite differently.  I have two HDRIs that I made: one from the start position of my object and another from the end position in the second room.

What's the best way to make use of both of them as my object walks from one room to the next in a single take?

Comment: Well, one way would be to use a mix shader on the world material and animate the mix factor between the two environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this - the image changes as the camera (Object) moves - the clamp node ensures the colors do not oversaturate as the mix factor goes high (beyond 1):

[image: Slide]

You can use other math nodes to slow down the "wipe" or change it's direction (I just noticed it's going the opposing way of the movement in my example - should be inverted). You can also use a Greater Than (Math) node to make the transition instantaneous at a certain point.

Comment: That makes total sense.  I had visions of making gigantic hemispheres of lights and setting them to be invisible during renders or something.  Many thanks